# terminal android - Сброс настроек

Tags: android, terminal

Какую команду написать в терминале, чтобы выполнился сброс настроек? Именно настроек, а не `wipe data/factory reset`.

Comment: Какие именно *настройки* вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: *Сброс настроек* и есть `wipe data/factory reset`. Другого сброса не существует.